# Python: Looking to create dictionary with pandas from a csv

Tags: python

Here is the dataframe

```
          SKU  Green Ball  Brown Ball  Black Ball  Free Gifts  Special Eq
0  Double Set         1.0         1.0         NaN         1.0         NaN
1  Green Ball         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2  Brown Ball         NaN         1.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
3  Free Gifts         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN
4  Special Eq         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         1.0
5  Ultima Set         1.0         1.0         NaN         1.0         1.0
```

The dictionary I want to create

```
{
    'Double Set': {'Green Ball': 1.0, 'Brown Ball': 1.0, 'Free Gifts': 1.0},
    'Green Ball': {'Green Ball': 1.0},
    'Brown ball': {'Brown Ball': 1.0},
    'Free Gifts': {'Free Gifts': 1.0},
    'Special Eq': {'Special Eq': 1.0},
    'Ultima Set': {'Green Ball': 1.0, 'Brown Ball': 1.0, 'Free Gifts': 1.0, 'Special Eq': 1.0},
}
```

How can I create the above dictionary and also exclude all values looked up to be `NaN`?

Comment: The question have nothing to do with csv, maybe you can use a more accurate title.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**:

1. Create `df`
2. Convert `df` to `dict`
3. Look for `value==Nan` as `del_item`
4. Remove `del_item`

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## step 1
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['SKU', 'Green Ball', 'Brown Ball', 'Black Ball', 'Free Gifts', 'Special Eq'],
    data=[
        ['Double Set', '1.0', '1.0', np.nan, '1.0', np.nan],
        ['Green Ball', '1.0', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        ['Brown Ball', np.nan, '1.0', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        ['Free Gifts', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '1.0', np.nan],
        ['Special Eq', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '1.0'],
        ['Ultima Set', '1.0', '1.0', np.nan, '1.0', '1.0']
    ]
)

## step 2
df = df.set_index('SKU')
obj = df.to_dict("index")

## step 3
del_item = []
for key1 in obj.keys():
    for key2 in obj[key1].keys():
        if pd.isna(obj[key1][key2]):
            del_item.append((key1,key2))
            
## step 4
for k1,k2 in del_item:
    del obj[k1][k2]
    
print(obj)
```

**Result**:

```
{
    'Double Set': {'Green Ball': '1.0', 'Brown Ball': '1.0', 'Free Gifts': '1.0'}, 
    'Green Ball': {'Green Ball': '1.0'}, 
    'Brown Ball': {'Brown Ball': '1.0'}, 
    'Free Gifts': {'Free Gifts': '1.0'}, 
    'Special Eq': {'Special Eq': '1.0'}, 
    'Ultima Set': {'Green Ball': '1.0', 'Brown Ball': '1.0', 'Free Gifts': '1.0', 'Special Eq': '1.0'}
}
```

Comment: `'NaN'` is not equal to `NaN`. you can change it to `np.nan`.

Comment: @AruneshSingh You are right, fixed.

Comment: Hey @ytung-dev, you forgot to import `numpy` as `np`. The code as it stands doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

Below is another approach:

1. Set SKU as index of dataframe.
2. Take transpose to make the index of dataframe as columns.
3. Next, you could use `to_dict` and pass `dict` as argument since we want `dict` values too as `dict` only.
4. Only thing left now is to filter out `NaNs`

   ```
   {k: pd.Series(v).dropna().to_dict()
        for k, v in df.set_index('SKU').T.to_dict('dict').items()}
   ```